# Is there a way to beat AlphaGo Zero with different method?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, alphago-zero

As I read the research from

https://deepmind.com/research

It seem AlphagoZero use zero knowledge and use Reinforcement learning to improve the ai skill of playing.

Is there a way to beat AlphagoZero? can anyone share an idea.

My friend said we can find a specific move to beat AlphagoZero.

From my point of view I think the only way to beat AlphagoZero is computational power.

But I can't find any other way to beat AlphagoZero, I hope there is many other way to beat it.

Also wanna keep some related topic below:

[Would AlphaGo Zero become perfect with enough training time?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/7914/would-alphago-zero-become-perfect-with-enough-training-time?rq=1)